# Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, semantic-versioning

I was working on a simple Ionic App.

Steps taken:

- updated ionic - OK
- started new project - OK
- created a couple of pages- OK
- served the app - OK

but then I tried to add the android platform:

> *ionic platform add android*

and got this error:

> ERROR: Cannot find module 'semver'
>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>
> Caught exception:
>    undefined

Any idea on why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried npm install ? You could also clean your node_modules folder

Answer (score 1):

i faced same issue and i fix with below coment

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just missing a node module dependency. Try running `npm install semver` inside your project dir.